# Is there any way how to publish my snippets on SO?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

I've written some nice and well commented code snippets I would like to publish on Stackoverflow for the others. Nevertheless I wasn't able to find out if there is even this possibility. Does anybody know, if SO has some service for posting code snippets?

Comment: I put a blog together of my best Stack Overflow answers.  I've seen other people on Stack Overflow do the same.  I've kept my writing skills up by writing for the blog.  Maybe you could publish a blog with your code interests?

Comment: Seems like a nice idea to me :) thx for a tip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no such feature. Stack Overflow isn't a blog service or a code hosting service.

You can use the "About Me" box in your profile for this though. Post a few links to your favorite snippets or to your snippet repository.

The other thing you can do is "disguise" your snippets in self-answered Q&A pairs. But if you go this route, please keep in mind that self-answered questions are subject to the same rules as all others. You must have a real question, with a concrete problem that your code snippet would address. (And the snippet would need to be included in the answer, not just linked to.)

Comment: thanks... I just have a few snippets on my HDD, I've written a few months ago so I just wanted to post them somewhere :]

Comment: You can use things like https://gist.github.com/ to share your snippets easily (and post links to those in your profile) for example.

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to come up with a valid interesting question for each of the snippets so that the snippet answers the question, then feel free to post the questions and post the snippets as answers (with comments and explanations).